# Cross Browser Compatible localStorage/cookie code not running in IE

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, cross-browser, local-storage

```
(function (window) {
  localStorage = local_store = {
    getItem: function (skey) {
        if (!skey) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!window.localStorage) {
            return unescape(document.cookie.replace(new RegExp("(?:^|.*;\\s*)" + escape(skey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=\\s*((?:[^;](?!;))*[^;]?).*"), "$1"));
        } else {
            return window.localStorage.getItem(skey);
        }
    },
    key: function (nkeyid) {
        if (!window.localStorage) {
            return unescape(document.cookie.replace(/\s*\=(?:.(?!;))*$/, "").split(/\s*\=(?:[^;](?!;))*[^;]?;\s*/)[nkeyid]);
        } else {
            window.localStorage.key(nkeyid);
        }
    },
    setItem: function (skey, sValue) {
        if (!skey) {
            return;
        }

        if (!window.localStorage) {
            document.cookie = escape(skey) + "=" + escape(sValue) + "; expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT; path=/";
            this.length = document.cookie.match(/\=/g).length;
        } else {
            window.localStorage.setItem(skey, sValue);
            this.length++;
        }
    },
    length: (document.cookie.match(/\=/g) || window.localStorage).length,
    removeItem: function (skey) {
        if (skey || !this.hasOwnProperty(skey)) {
            return;
        }
        if (!window.localStorage) {
            document.cookie = escape(skey) + "=;expires=Thu,01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;path=/";
            this.length--;
        } else {
            window.localStorage.removeItem(skey);
        }
    },
    hasOwnProperty: function (skey) {
        if (!window.localStorage) {
            return (new RegExp("(?:^/;\\s*)" + escape(skey).replace(/[\-\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "\\s*\\=")).test(document.cookie);
        } else {
            return window.localStorage.hasOwnProperty();
        }
    },
    returnObj: function () {
        if (!window.localStorage) {
            return document.cookie;
        } else {
            return window.localStorage;
        }
    }
};
window.local_store = local_store.hasOwnProperty ? local_store.returnObj() : local_store;
}(window));
```

Code above runs in other browsers though in IE10 I get an error of :

`Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference`

And it's pointing to the `localStorage= local_store = {` part of the code.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

http://jsbin.com/OdajuGO/1/edit  For testing purposes

Comment: Anyone? The question is quite simple to those of whom are more proficient at IE cross browser detections.

Comment: Even though the error is pointing to `localStorage= local_store = {`, the error might be in `length: (document.cookie.match(/\=/g) || window.localStorage).length`. If the error is not there, then you may want to re-design your program.